# Using same onClick listener with more than one view

Tags: android, onclick, listeners

I am using the same onClick listener for a number of items.

When I click I want to know which one.

I know that I can do a Switch statement on the getId() but would rather be able to get at the name of the item.
Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say name of the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are referring to when you say "get the name" is the id string from resources. So you would have a switch statement like:

```
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.HomeButtonOne:
        // Do Button One Action
        break;
    case R.id.HomeButtonTwo:
        // Do Button Two Action
        break;
}
```

otherwise please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The reason I want the name is that it gives me a pointer into a vector. The last letter of the name is a digit which will give me the pointer.

Comment: Well if you use the above code, just set the pointer of the vector depending on the view ID, if speed is a concern and memory isn't a huge concern, then why not use a hashmap to get faster lookup, using the id as the key. NOTE: all I would say is stop referring to this as "the name" the ID represents an integer, and "the name" you are referring to is the variable name. To find out the variable name, the simple switch statement above gives you that.

Comment: Maybe you could add an unique android:tag string to each button in the XML. Then you can grab the 'data' by using view.getTag("myTag"). I am not sure it is what you need, but I comment just in case anyone can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have  a few options.

1. You could extend View with a class which you create and includes additional identifiable information.  Then in onClick, cast the View to your class type.
2. You could use an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html) to better manager your views.  This works best if you are displaying views of data instead of inert layouts or Drawables.

It's going to boil down to what you want to store and what you are viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a class which implements OnClickListner and set an instance to your views:

```
class MyListener implements OnClickListener() {
 // ...
}

MyListener listener = new MyListener();

View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
view.setOnClickListener(listener);
view = (View) findViewById(R.id.myAnotherViewId);
view.setOnClickListener(listener);

...
```

Comment: Since they are all the same how does it help? I did consider writing a listener for each item but was worried about the overhead of multiple instantiations.