# Getting the current active editTextField when two or more editTextFields are using same event listener?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two editTextField, the same listener is attached to both of them. How would I figure out in the listener which one is clicked?

```
inputStart = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
inputStart.setOnClickListener(TimePickerButtonOnClickListener);

inputEnd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
inputEnd.setOnClickListener(TimePickerButtonOnClickListener);

private Button.OnClickListener TimePickerButtonOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {         
     public void onClick(View v) {       }
};
```

I have checked, one possible solution is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224659/using-same-onclick-listener-with-more-than-one-view),
but I am looking for any property like `EditText gotEditField = (EditText)v.targetEditField;`

Does any such property exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View v` from the parameters in your `onCLick` method is the view that was clicked.

```
EditText gotEditField = (EditText) v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **switch case**, in `onClick()` with parameter `View v` using `v.getId()`

```
private Button.OnClickListener TimePickerButtonOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
{           
  public void onClick(View v) { 
       switch(v.getId){
         case R.id.editText3:
         break;
         .
         .
         .
       }
};
```

Also you can get the object of **EditText** using Type Casting the `View v` parameter..

Like `EditText editText = (EditText)v;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    int id= v.getId();

    switch (id) 
    {
        case R.id.editText3:  
        break;

        case R.id.editText4:    
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @KANAIYA You can see the edit by clicking on the "x mins ago" link. Please also note, that the edit was reviewed by someone and accepted.